# Can I use Canon EF-S lens designed for crop sensor with a full-frame Sony E mount camera?

Tags: sony, lens-adapter, full-frame, aps-c, ef-s

Considering an Canon EF/EF-S mount adapter for a Sony E mount camera.

Will a full frame A series sony camera like the A7s II be able to use a EF-S lens?

I am guessing that yes, because the sony camera does not have a mirror that flips, then the back of an APS-C lens will not threaten the inner chassis of the camera.

It is just counterintuitive after all these years of having such a clear distinction between full frame and crop sensor lenses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use EF-S lenses on a Sony A7s II. The camera has a crop mode that will automatically crop the image to match the APS-C image of the EF-S lenses.

You can also turn off the crop mode and shoot full frame mode with EF-S lenses. Wide angle lenses like the EF-S 10-18 STM and EF-S 10-22 will not vignette at all when used at 14mm-22mm.

Comment: This sounds adapter dependent.  Plain and dumb adapters presumably will mount any EF or EF-S lens, but adapters that have electronics may or may nor work with any given lens.  You'd need to research any specific lens and ("smart") adapter combination.  Note that AFAIK Canon full frame DSLRs will generally not work with EF-S lenses at all.

Answer (score 3):

You're correct in that the lens will mount and there's obviously no mirror to foul on the lens - but remember that EF-S lenses throw an image circle which is only as large as an APS-C sensor, so you'll get *severe* vignetting if used on a full frame sensor. Exactly how much depends on the lens - the EF-S 10-22 can actually be used relatively successfully even on a full frame Canon SLR, but other lenses are probably in the "don't bother" category.